# Is it possible to generate separate .exe files for ARM and THUMB?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, embedded, arm, thumb

I have an embedded c++ project for WM6. In some devices I use a printer library that is not compatible with Linker settings "MACHINE:ARM". So I have to build 2 .exe files. One for THUMB machine and another for ARM machine that some lines of code must be commented to avoid compile error. Is it possible to generate 2 .exe files and build them in 2 separated folders one for ARM and another for THUMB?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

An additional configuration could be added using the configuration manager.

You can then define a compilation constant in the build tab of the ARM configuration. Explained in the answer to [How do I create my own defined constants based on the "Configuration Manager"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981170/visual-studio-how-do-i-create-my-own-defined-constants-based-on-the-configurat)